# Fetching the JSON value

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I need to fetch the values from this JSON in my java script:

```
[{
        "selectionName": "Select",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 4,
                "subSelectionName": "Select",
                "description": "Deepmala"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "selectionName": "week14",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 7,
                "subSelectionName": "1",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "selectionName": "test",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 6,
                "subSelectionName": "test",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "selectionName": "select",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 3,
                "subSelectionName": "sub-select",
                "description": "Created by Prakash"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "selectionName": "testcreate",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 1,
                "subSelectionName": "testcreate",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "selectionName": "by htmlwidget",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 5,
                "subSelectionName": "by htmlwidget",
                "description": "created by html widget"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: which values do you want?  selectionName? id? description?  can you clarify?

Comment: What is your problem? Show us the code you've tried.

Comment: I am trying to fetch the value in my java script like this:

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like JSONSelect to extract certain values.

http://jsonselect.org/

Here's an example of how to use it:

(found in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molokoloco/7PTAQ/))

```
$(function(){
/*
Json as easy as SQL ??? RT @lloydhilaiel JSONSelect - CSS-like selectors for JSON - http://jsonselect.org
Testing...
*/
var jsonData = {
    "name": {
        "first": "Lloyd",
        "last": "Hilaiel"
    },
    "favoriteColor": "yellow",
    "languagesSpoken": [
        {
        "language": "Bulgarian",
        "level": 2},
    {
        "language": "English",
        "level": 1},
    {
        "language": "Spanish",
        "level": 7}
    ]
};

var selector = '.name > *'; // xPath CSS like selector

try {

    var resultObj = JSONSelect.match(selector, jsonData);
    console.log(typeof resultObj);
    console.log(resultObj);
    console.log('- - - - -');

    JSONSelect.forEach(selector, jsonData, function(resultObj) {
        console.log(typeof resultObj);
        console.log(resultObj);
        console.log('- - - - -');
        $('body').append('<p>' + $.trim(JSON.stringify(resultObj, null, ' ')) + '</p>');
    });

} catch(e) { console.log(e); }

});
```

Comment: the json I am geting is from jsp function getSelection() {
  var options = ""; 
 
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/r3/selection.jsp').done(function(json) {
   // var data ='http:../r3/selection.jsp';
   
    alert(json.selectionName);
   // alert(json.subSelections);
 value.selectionName + '</option>';
      $.each(json.subSelections, function(index, value) {           
       options += '<option value="' + value. subSelectionName + '">' + value. description + '</option>';
 });

    
  }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    alert(' fail   : '+error);
  });
  
  
}

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects are easy to handle

```
var JSON = //Your JSON Object

JSON[0].selectName //returns 'Select'

JSON[0].subSelections[0].id //returns 4

and so on.
```

Any array objects can be treated as arrays.  Any mapped objects can be returned by using the key like a field name for the JSON object.